# Use of safe prime in RSA digital signature scheme

Tags: digital-signature, rsa

For the RSA digital signature scheme , Alice has a pair of public and private keys as denoted by

`Public key : (e,n)`

`Private key : (d,n)`

Assuming Alice wants to send a message M to Bob , she would produce an encrypted message EM = M<sup>e</sup> mod n.

e would have to be chosen such that `gcd( e,(p-1)(q-1) ) = 1`. My lecturer states that to give it additional security , `e` should **also** be [safe prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_prime) where `e = 2q + 1 , q` is also prime

1. Is it really necessary to use safe prime for e , is it alright to just use `gcd( e,(p-1)(q-1) ) = 1`, what would happen if we don't use a safe prime?
2. Why do safe prime provide additional security?
3. Can this be applied to RSA encryption scheme?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The need for a "safe prime" is a piece of old lore that is now obsolete, but is still taught, because of what can only be described as generalized apathy.

**Historically**, the "safe primes" are called "safe" because of [Pollard's *p*-1 factorization algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_p_%E2%88%92_1_algorithm).

The core idea of Pollard's algorithm is the following: when we compute things modulo *n* (*n* = *pq* for two big primes *p* and *q*), we are actually doing the computation modulo *p* and modulo *q* (that's the gist of the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)). So we will do computations modulo *n* and hope for things to go sour: we want to do things that yield a value of zero modulo *p* but not modulo *q*, because, when working modulo *n* (as we do), such a situation implies that we got some integer *x* that is not invertible modulo *n*; such an *x* is a multiple of *p* but not of *q*; thus, a simple [GCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) between *n* and *x* yields *p*, and *n* is factored.

In this case, Pollard says: let's suppose that *p*-1 is "smooth", meaning that it is a product of only small prime factors. For instance, suppose that the largest prime factor of *p*-1 is smaller than some bound *B* (we would then say that *p*-1 is "*B*-smooth"). Then, take a random value *z* modulo *n* and do this:

- Replace *z* with *z*<sup>2<sup>*k*</sup></sup> mod *n*, where *k* is the largest integer such that 2<sup>*k*</sup> < *p*.
- Replace *z* with *z*<sup>3<sup>*k*</sup></sup> mod *n*, where *k* is the largest integer such that 3<sup>*k*</sup> < *p*.
- Replace *z* with *z*<sup>5<sup>*k*</sup></sup> mod *n*, where *k* is the largest integer such that 5<sup>*k*</sup> < *p*.
- ... and so on, in due succession, for all primes up to *B*.

If *p*-1 is indeed *B*-smooth, then, at that point, *z* is necessarily equal to 1 modulo *p* (because all the exponentiations have collectively raised *z* to an exponent *u* that is a multiple of *p*-1). Thus, *z*-1 is a multiple of *p*. But if *q* is not *B*-smooth, then *z*-1 is not a multiple of *q*. Therefore, a GCD between *z*-1 and *n* yields *p*, and *n* is factored.

(Note that everything here is about factoring *n*, which is sufficient to break the RSA key generally, regardless of whether you use it for signing or for encrypting.)

To avoid falling into the situation where *p*-1 is *B*-smooth for a *B* small enough for the algorithm above to be practical, some people have said: let's generate our *p* such that *p* = 2⁠*r* + 1 (for some prime *r*). Such a *p* is *B*-smooth only for *B* at least as large than *r*, i.e. almost as large as *p*; this is way too large for Pollard's *p*-1 algorithm to work in any non-ridiculous amount of time. We well thus deem such primes "safe". Neat, isn't it ? Not so fast.

**"Safe" primes are not safe**, or at least not safer than randomly generated primes. The first blow came in 1982, eight years after Pollard's publication, when Williams invented the [*p*+1 factorization algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Williams%27_p_%2B_1_algorithm). It is a generalization of Pollard's algorithm, that works whenever *p*-1 or *p*+1 is *B*-smooth for a small enough *B*. This means that if you want your *p* to be "safe", then you must ensure that *both* *p*-1 and *p*+1 are the product of a large enough prime; you would need to generate *p* such that *p* = 2⁠*r* + 1 *and* *p* = 2⁠*r'* - 1 for two primes *r* and *r'*.

Then the notion of "safe prime" for factorization was killed in 1987 when Lenstra published the [ECM factorization method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic_curve_factorization). It can be viewed as a generalization of Pollard's *p*-1 algorithm. We work modulo *n*; we define a random elliptic curve of equation *Y*<sup>2</sup> = *X*<sup>3</sup> + *aX* + *b* for two random integers *a* and *b* modulo *n*. Then we take a random point *G* on that curve; and we *multiply* that point repeatedly, with 2<sup>*k*</sup>, 3<sup>*k*</sup>, 5<sup>*k*</sup>... and so on, up to bound *B* (each "*k*" being adjusted so that the multiple is not greater than *p*).

These point multiplications are really the analogous of the exponentiations in Pollard's algorithm. Our hope is that the curve order modulo *p* is *B*-smooth, i.e. that all these point multiplications will send our point to the "point at infinity" when considering it modulo *p*. There again, when we do elliptic curve computations modulo *n*, we are actually working over two curves at the same time, one modulo *p* and one modulo *q*. If we reach the "point at infinity" on the curve modulo *p* (but not modulo *q*), this will show up as non-invertible coordinates *X* and *Y* modulo *n*, and, again, a simple GCD then reveals the factorization.

The **crucial point**, for the discussion at hand, is that ECM will work if the *curve order* (for the curve "modulo *p*") is *B*-smooth. That curve order is "close" to *p*, but still fairly randomly distributed in a range of size 4·sqrt(*p*), which is quite large (if we are talking about 1024-bit primes, then the range has size at least 2<sup>512</sup>...). Therefore, a RSA modulus will resist ECM factorization only because a *random* 1024-bit integer in a large range has only negligible probability of being *B*-smooth for a small enough *B*.

Remember that the notion of generating a "safe prime" comes from the fear that a randomly generated prime *p* could turn out to be such that *p*-1 is *B*-smooth. Fortunately, the probability of such an occurrence with normal-sized primes (say, 1024 bits for RSA-2048) is abysmally small. But some people say that they want to "take no risk" and they insist on verifying that *p*-1 is not *B*-smooth. The ECM method shows that it is flawed thinking: regardless of how you select *p*, you are still relying on the very small probability of a random integer to be *B*-smooth.

**Summary:** there is no reason to single out *p*-1 as needing a big enough prime factor. For security, you *need* random integer generation to be "safe enough" (not *B*-smooth for too small a *B*); and if a random integer is fine, then it is fine. Insistence on using "safe primes" for RSA is just being stuck in the past; it *made* sense between 1974 and 1987, but no longer.

---

**Notes:**

- Though "safe primes" are a useless notion for RSA, they still have some use in Diffie-Hellman, since they allow the use of a small integer as generator (typically 2), which has some (slight) performance benefits.
- Regardless of all of the above, confronting your lecturer is socially and politically a poor move. If he (she) is a nice open-minded guy (or gal), you *might* want to send him (her) to me, i.e. point him (her) to that answer. But in student-teacher relationships, the best strategy for a student is to watch, learn, and bide his time.

Comment: what an awesome answer

Comment: @Tom: bid -> bide

Comment: Doesn’t the [Cramer-Shoup signature scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%E2%80%93Shoup_cryptosystem) use safe primes for other reasons than their supposed hardness to factor ?